# Ruby's rest-client isn't replicating my CURL request, and I don't know what I'm doing any differently

Tags: ruby, rest, http, rest-client, sinch

Here's my CURL request:

```
curl  -X POST -u apikey:secret 'https://numbers.api.sinch.com/v1/projects/{project ID}/availableNumbers:rentAny' \
  -d '{
    "regionCode": "US",
    "type": "LOCAL",
    "numberPattern": {
      "pattern": "206",
      "searchPattern": "START"
    },
    "smsConfiguration": {
      "servicePlanId": "{service plan ID}"
    }
  }'
```

I receive a 200 response, and everything works as expected.

Here's what I'm doing with Ruby's `rest-client`:

```
opts = {
  :method=>:post,
  :payload=>{"smsConfiguration"=>{"servicePlanId"=>"service plan ID"}, "numberPattern"=>{"pattern"=>"206", "searchPattern"=>"START"}, "regionCode"=>"US", "type"=>"LOCAL"},
  :url=>"https://numbers.api.sinch.com/v1/projects/{project ID}/availableNumbers:rentAny",
  :headers=>{},
  :user=>"API key",
  :password=>"secret"
}

begin
  RestClient::Request.execute(opts)
rescue RestClient::BadRequest => e
  puts e.response.body
end
```

This returns a 400 response. The statement printed:

```
"{\"error\":{\"code\":400,\"message\":\"invalid character 's' looking for beginning of value\",\"status\":\"INVALID_ARGUMENT\",\"details\":[]}}\n"
```

I expected a 200 response from my `rest-client`, using the same data from my CURL request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the API is expecting a JSON document in the request body, you need to tell RestClient this, otherwise, it will produce a POST request with a content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and form-encoded body.

Use `to_json` on your body to encode it, and add `headers: { content_type: :json }` to tell RestClient to make a JSON request.

```
RestClient::Request.execute(
  method: :post,
  payload: { "smsConfiguration" => { ... } }.to_json,
  headers: { 
    content_type: :json,
  },
  # ...
)
```

Note that, in your first example, it would be more correct to also include the `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers in your CURL request, but it seems likely that the API assumes JSON in the case that those headers aren't set.

However, RestClient cannot make this assumption, you need to specifically tell it you are intending to send JSON.

Comment: hey thanks! Yeah, basically I just needed to convert my payload `to_json`.
Side note about the headers, I did try adding `content_type: :json` in the past. It works fine without it, but yeah it's neater to put it in anyways.